# Specify database engine while creating models in django

Tags: django, django-models

This is stored in the settings file -

```
DATABASES = {
 'default': {
    'ENGINE'  : 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME'    : 'db_test',
    'USER'    : 'root',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST'    : 'localhost',
    'PORT'    : '',
    'CONN_MAX_AGE': 45,
    'OPTIONS' : {
        'init_command': 'SET storage_engine=INNODB',
    }
},
```

there is one table that I need to create with MYISAM engine, how can I set that while defining the model.

For example -

class Test(models.Model):
    def **unicode**(self):
        return '%s' % self.name

```
class Meta:
    db_table = 'Test'

user = models.CharField(max_length=100)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
type = models.IntegerField()
```

I need to create this table in MYISAM without changing the settings file.
How can I do that?

Comment: I know this is old but did you solved this issue. I also have a similar problem

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried migrations? It should work.

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    ...

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL('ALTER TABLE __your_table__ ENGINE=MYISAM;')
    ]
```

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/migration-operations/#runsql

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to do it manually.

Remove

```
'OPTIONS' : {
    'init_command': 'SET storage_engine=INNODB',
}
```

from your settings and perform

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> ENGINE=MYISAM;
```

after Django create table for your model.